# error "too many cell format" with only one cell

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I don't understand where is the problem. I know about the recurring "too many cell formats" in VBA excel, but now I have the problem with a simple line of code:

```
If color <> -1 Then
 ActiveCell.Interior.color = Cell_Color
End If
```

Where activecell is only a cell. Can you explain me why I got this problem ? How can I handle it without add-ins ?

Comment: what are your `Cell_color` and `color` variable values when you error occurs? Can you provide more of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was quite surprised to have a "too many cell format" with only one cell because I tought excel was talking about the format of that cell. In fact this has nothing to do with the formats in the selection.

Its about a problem, only in excel 2003 where cells format are kept in memory, even unused ones. The number of cell format is also kept in a variable. Which is an integer and so is bounded to 65.000+. the problem appears when it is no more possible to increase the number of cell formats due to the integer limit.

Before this problems appears, a high number of cells formats can cause slowness of the macros. See the second answer here to clean unused cell format:

[Too Many Different Cell Formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449755/too-many-different-cell-formats)