# ActiveWorkbook.Styles returning Nothing due to "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients"

Tags: excel, vba, module

I found the following Macro to clean up a workbook of 60k+ styles: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933399

Every time I run this macro Excel crashes with the error "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" on the line `For Each styleObj In wb.Styles`. This causes styleObj to be Nothing (i.e. null) and crashes the script.

What am I doing wrong? the `wb.Styles.Count` lines work perfectly, however everything below that breaks. I am using Excel 2010.

Even simple code like this fails in the same way at the beginning of the for loop:

```
Sub KillCustomStyles()
Dim mpStyle As Style
    For Each mpStyle In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
        If Not mpStyle.BuiltIn Then
            mpStyle.Delete
        End If
    Next mpStyle
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Had you stuck to the example you linked, it would have worked.
If you do it the direct way...

```
For Each mpStyle In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
...
   mpStyle.Delete
```

...you are changing the very collection you are iterating through, i.e. your loop becomes invalid because you change its base.

Instead, you should create a separate collection of styles:

```
Sub KillCustomStyles()
Dim styleObj As Style
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary    ' <- from Tools / References... / "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"
Dim aKey As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim Str As String

For Each styleObj In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
    Str = styleObj.NameLocal
    i = IIf(styleObj.BuiltIn, 1, 0) 'if builtin: 1, else 0
    Call dict.Add(Str, i)    ' First time:  adds keys
Next styleObj

For Each aKey In dict
    If dict.Item(aKey) = 0 Then '0: not builtin
        ActiveWorkbook.Styles(aKey).Delete
    End If
Next aKey

End Sub
```

This code is drawn almost 1:1 from the linked SO post. Look sharp and you see that first there is a separate collection filled with styles, you iterate over this collection, but delete from wb.Styles

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot 'if mpstyle.locked = true' as I said in the original answer I am unsure what the .locked property is but this may be the reason it didn't work. Here is the code I use again:

```
Sub NukeStyles()
Dim tempstyle As Style

For Each tempstyle In ActiveWorkbook.Styles

If tempstyle.BuiltIn = False Then
   If tempstyle.Locked = True Then 'not sure what this is but I need it
      tempstyle.Delete
   End If
End If

Next tempstyle

End Sub 'NukeStyles
```

'--------------------------------------