# How to standardize data formats in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm collecting data from many workbooks. The problem is, in every document the date format is not consistent:
16/01/2015
2015-01-06
**24.03.2014**

What I want to achieve is "YYYY-MM-DD" format. In my code I've a case which responsible to clear the date columns. Now I'm getting desperate and I added stupid amount of date formatting to the code, but no changes when it comes to the dotted format (one with bold above). Even If I select manually the column and change the format type, or copy the values to a .txt file then copy back to the original sheet, also tried with a new WorkBook, but nothing happened. Why is it impossible to change the date values in this few instances? Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code:

```
        Case 6:

    sourceWorkbook.Activate
    sourceWS.Activate

    sourceWS.Columns(i).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD;@"
    sourceWS.Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(lastrw, i)).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD;@"


        For j = startRow To lastrw Step 1
            'Assign the header to the first row
            NewWorksheet.Cells(1, i) = sourceWS.Cells(startRow, i).Value

            On Error Resume Next
                textToFormat = CStr(sourceWS.Cells(j, i).Value)

                d = CDate(textToFormat)
                finalDate = Format(textToFormat, "YYYY-MM-DD")

                NewWorksheet.Cells(j - adjustRows, i) = finalDate
                'This error handler purpose to handle the header name!
                If Err Then

                    NewWorksheet.Cells(j - adjustRows, i) = textToFormat

                End If

            On Error GoTo 0

        Next j
        Set fckFormat = NewWorksheet.Columns(i)
        fckFormat.NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD;@"
        NewBook.Activate
        NewWorksheet.Activate
        NewWorksheet.Columns(i).Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD;@"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too Many Different Cell Formats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449755/too-many-different-cell-formats)

Comment: See answer that start by : **Lots of people seem to run into this problem.**

Comment: @R3uK , you mean in the source sheet or in the code? I tested the code it works for every other formats, except the mentioned one.

Comment: The cells that hold the date values in `24.03.2014` format, are they formatted as dates or strings?

Comment: +1 for @Jordan question! Does changing manually the format affect the content displayed in a date cell? And I was suggest the utility that you can find here : https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AArEUjrx0NkTCUM&id=53E1D37F76F69444%21526&cid=53E1D37F76F69444

Comment: Do a find/replace on all columns affected, swapping `.` for `/`.

Comment: If all of the different dates are stored as dates in the cells (and not strings) you can simply use `.Value2` to extract the date as a `Double` and then use `Format(value, "yyyy-mm-dd")` to convert them to your desired format.

Comment: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/convert-to-date.htm

Answer (score 0):

As Jordan suggested, the issue is that this data is formatted as a string rather than a date. For example if I enter each of the dates above in a new workbook, the first two are correctly detected as dates (and can be formatted as such) while the last one is treated as a text string. This may vary based on your regional settings.

Unfortunately, the CDate function is also failing to recognise this format as a valid date. Try running the following, and you'll get a Type mismatch error:

```
MsgBox CDate("24.03.2016")
```

You can use the Replace Method to convert this in to a valid date, by replacing the dot  with a slash:

```
Set datecol = Sheets(1).Columns(1) 
datecol.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

The cell will still be formatted as a string, but you can now use your existing loop to convert it to a date using CDate:

```
            d = CDate(textToFormat)
            NewWorksheet.Cells(j - adjustRows, i) = d
```

The NumberFormat will then work correctly.

Note: I would suggest using CDate rather than Format so that the date is still stored as a value rather than text.